# how to open a pop up window at the bottom right corner of the screen

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a button click on which a pop up opens using javascript window.open.

My code looks like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
window.open('', '', 'height=5,width=5');
}
</script>
```

now the pop up opens at the top left corner of the screen.
How to set the pop up so that it opens at the bottom right corner so that the user is not aware of pop up open ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What @polkovnikov.ph said, but here is info on it if you are dead set. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: yeah tried the same.but unable to fix the position at the bottom right of my screen

Answer (score 10):

If you mean (window size) - (popup size) it would be like this:

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var height = 5,
          width = 5
          t = window.innerHeight-height,
          l = window.innerWidth-width;

      window.open('', '', 'height='+height+', width='+width+', left='+l+', top='+t );
  }
</script>
```

Where:

- t = bottom - popup height
- l = right - popup width

Be aware this example is for Chrome/Firefox/...
IE uses a different sintax to retrieve the window size values

Comment: tried this..Still its opening in the centre of the screen

Comment: Which browser are you using? Just tested it works fine in Chome and FF

Answer (score 2):

```
    <p>Click the button to open a new window.</p>
    <button onclick="openWindow()">Open</button>
    <script>
        var topsss=screen.height-490;
        var left=screen.width-420;
        function openWindow() {
            window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top="+topsss+",left="+left+",width=420,height=490");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: this will get blocked by popup blockers.

Answer (score 0):

window.open(url, name, specs, replace) is correct but you are passing height and width as specs arguments. Try replacing them with top and left.